# html + Js code not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning to link js with html so I wrote this but it didn't work 
I need to know what's the problem with it!!
Code :

```
 <Html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <Script>
    Function test() {
    Alert(document.getElementById("input").value);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <Body>
    <form>
    <fieldset>
    <input Type="text" name="input" id="input" />
    <Button onClick="test()"> alert</button>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </Body>
    </Html>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typos.

Comment: There is no such thing as a `Function` or `Alert` in javascript.... :-(

Comment: @qwertynl — There is a `Function`, it's a construction function.

Comment: @ M_5_A: Key take-away: JavaScript is *case-sensitive*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very low quality question. You haven't told us what you expect this code to do (alert the contents of the text box, I assume). In the future, please do *not* use "it doesn't work" as a description of a problem. I'll cut you some slack since it looks like you're new, though.

Anyways, if you had opened up the JavaScript console in the browser, you would have seen a syntax error (or "Unexpected Identifier") on Line 5. That's where you declare your `test()` function. Let's have a look at it:

```
Function test() {
  Alert(document.getElementById("input").value);
}
```

Notice you're using "Function". JavaScript is *case sensitive*, which means that `function` and `Function` mean two completely different things. You want `function`, which is the keyword.

Similarly, there is no such function as `Alert()`. You'll want to use `alert()` instead.

The fixed code is:

```
function test() {
  alert(document.getElementById("input").value);
}
```

Good luck in your learning!

Comment: That whole first paragraph is a *comment*, not an answer, and should be in a comment on the question, not in an answer to the question.

Comment: How ironic that I get lectured on my lecture :) You're completely right of course.

Answer (score 4):

Check your console. There's no function called `Alert()`. It's case sensitive. You're looking for `alert();` and it should be `function` with a lowercase "F".

Also, inline JavaScript (such as `onclick` in your html) is bad practice. Study up on that here: https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F

By the way, html isn't case-sensitive, but it's standard practice to use lowercase. I think it's relevant to mention here since you're having case-sensitive issues with JavaScript.

Comment: And no such thing as `Function`

Comment: Also `Function` (which does exist but is a constructor function, not a keyword)

Comment: **JINX** @Quentin :-P

Comment: @qwertynl: Yes there is. But you don't want to use it the way it's used there.

Comment: That is true. but I meant in the OP's context @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error on your code

the script should be

```
 <Script>
    function test() {
    alert(document.getElementById("input").value);
    }
    </script>
```

both Function and Alert should be in small letters